# How to increase video memory for virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, memory, video, virtual-machine, adobe-photoshop

I have a Linux host running Windows 7 in a Virtualbox guest. I am trying to enable 3D accelerated functionality in Adobe Photoshop CC running on that guest, which [requires at least 512MB of VRAM](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cs6-gpu-faq1.html). However, Virtualbox seems to only support up to 256MB of video memory.

Do any other virtual machine hosts, such as VMware or KVM support allocating 512MB of VRAM? What other options do I have to meet Photoshop's VRAM requirements? (I would like to avoid dual booting OSes if possible).

Comment: For pure processing, today's VM's are practically as good as a dual-boot, but for memory intensive operations (like you're gonna have a lot of with PS) a dual-boot is superior.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Workstation version 10 don't have video memory restriccion of any kind. But the main problem is the price: **249 $**